# What is the purpose of a VPN?

Tags: vpn

A VPN connects a PC, smartphone, or tablet to another computer (called a server) somewhere on the internet. But, i could comunicate to another pc even without a VPN, so what is the purpose of using it ?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A VPN is a tunnel, usually encrypted, that connects two networks together as if they had a direct link between the two networks. Regardless of the number of hops it takes between the two networks, the tunnel looks like a single hop. The packets inside the tunnel are normally encrypted to maintain privacy (a company with two sites, or two companies, connected by a VPN over the public Internet want to keep proprietary information from falling into the wrong hands).

There are many reasons to use a tunnel. There are protocols that simply cannot be transported on the public Internet (multicast, routing protocols, etc.) that networks may need to share among themselves. Because the tunnel makes it look like a direct connection between the separated sites, and because the outer tunnel packets hide the inner packets, you can transport protocols across the Internet that cannot be transported by the Internet itself.

Comment: What does it mean that the VPN is a "virtual private network" ? What is a private network in this context ?

Comment: The network link inside the tunnel is private. The Internet is a public network, and it has rules that must be followed, including things like addressing and routing. What goes on inside the tunnel is separate from the Internet. You can have private addressing and routing protocols other than BGP.

Comment: So it's like having a long ethernet cable that connects the devices ?

Comment: Yes, the tunnel looks like a direct link between two sites.

Comment: However if i connect to another pc using a VPN i can navigate using its internet connection , but if i connect to another pc using ethernet i can't do that. So it seems there are differences...

Comment: That depends on the PC and its configuration. Unfortunately, host/server questions are off-topic here. It is certainly possible that a PC can be configured to bridge or route traffic between interfaces (a tunnel interface on a PC is just another interface, like an ethernet interface). You can ask about configuring your PC on [su].

Comment: So both ethernet and VPN ideally give the same possibilities. Is right ?

Comment: That is really too broad. We would need more context, but if you mean as interface on a host, then yes, an interface is an interface.

Comment: @AleQuercia The VPN can be set up to work that way, yes. So can the Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 3):

VPN stand for Virtual Private network. It makes secured tunnel through public internet. Generally we don't use VPN in Local area network and if you want to connect with your branch network in separate location, then best and secured solution will be VPN.

wikipedia Says

> A virtual private network extends a private network across a public
>   network, and enables users to send and receive data across shared or
>   public networks as if their computing devices were directly connected
>   to the private network.

There are two major type of VPNs.

- Site to site VPN
- Remote Site vpn

Especially VPN are secured because It transfer encrypted traffic. Based technically you can find many VPNs such as SSL,IPSec, Flex and many more....

Answer (score 3):

A VPN link mainly serves two purposes:

- transparent routing: the tunnel allows each side to transparently use the other side's addressing scheme (usually: private IP address space connect over public IP address space); since the source addresses may remain original, they can be used for security/trust
- encryption: traffic is completely encrypted; an eavesdropper can merely detect *that* there's traffic, but he can't get at the data and can't even see who is talking to whom (metadata), regardless of whether end-to-end encryption is used or not

Answer (score 0):

VPNs provide two main features.

1. They encrypt your traffic as it passes over the internet. While an increasing proportion of protocols do perform encryption at the application layer, there are still many that don't, and performing encryption at a network level allows you to hide metadata that would inevitably be visible with application level encryption.
2. They decouple your addressing and routing from the addressing and routing used by your providers.

This decoupling is useful for a number of reasons.

1. Having control of your addressing and routing, means you can more easily use firewalling and IP address based access control, either as a primary control, or as a defense-in-depth measure.
2. Having your own addressing and routing means you can use private addresses for your systems, while still allowing systems on different sites to talk to each other. While there are a few companies whose addressing needs are so large, that private space feels cramped to them, most companies will find private v4 much less space constrained than public v4.
3. Having your own addressing and routing means you can change internet providers without changing all of your addressing. For large sites it's possible to do this without a VPN by using provider-independent addresses, but this is less pracitcal for small sites.
4. Having your own addressing and routing means you can work around network problems. If the local "broadband" provider has crappy international connectivity and you are not using VPNs there is not much you can do. If you are using VPNs then you can potentially set up a local VPN endpoint with better international connectivity.
5. Having your own addressing and routing works around the potential presence of "outgoing connections only" firewalls and "carrier grade NAT" at broadband and mobile providers.

Answer (score -2):

Protect your passwords, finances, and even where you browse with a VPN. It scrambles your data like a secret code, keeping prying eyes out.
Say goodbye to online fingerprints! Websites track your every move, but a VPN throws on a mask and cloak, making you vanish online.
Work from anywhere, securely. VPNs act like fortresses for your internet connection, letting employees access company data safely even on the go.
A VPN encrypts your connection, turning sensitive information into gibberish for hackers. Break free from the tracking trail. Cookies and trackers follow you across the web, building a profile of your online life. A VPN throws them off the scent, hiding your true IP address.
Grant secure access to company networks from anywhere with the added peace of mind of a VPN's robust encryption and activity monitor.

Comment: A VPN doesn't protect passwords or local data. Where you surf is all visible to the VPN provider. Online fingerprinting and tracking isn't seriously obstructed by VPN - the public IP address you show is just a small hint for tracking. And most of your answer is off topic here.